# Can't add reference in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

I have recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2019, and I get a weird problem.

When I am trying to add a reference to the project, I get an error message that says "sequence contains no elements".

Do you know how to fix it? I have tried to reinstall, but for no avail…

Comment: what kind of reference are you trying to add ? projectreference, framework-assembly, local assembly, nuget ?

Answer (score 5):

1. Click 'Project' menu
2. Click 'Add Reference' sub menu
3. Click 'Browse...' button
4. In the file name texbox, paste : 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0' (or any other framework version)

Voila! - add the file you wish

Comment: It will not let me add a folder. Is there a specific DLL that needs added so that adding a reference to another project within the solution will work again? Currently checking or unchecking make no changes to my csproj file. The strange thing is that checking it will allow intellisense to work too until I rebuild then it says I'm missing a reference again!

Comment: from the above folder (depends on your framework version) - select the file
Good luck

Comment: @GuyCohen which file?

Comment: The one missing

Comment: Just adding a comment incase it helps others. I came here because I couldn't find the 'Add reference' sub menu under the Project menu. Solution is to click 'Refresh project toolbox items', it should appear after this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a test project I had renamed, when trying to get it to reference the project I wanted to test.
I got over the issue by unloading and reloading the test project.